# How to cast float to integer in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying  to assign a specific width to my image in asp.net (using vb.net).
So I used the next code:

```
<asp:Image ID="PercentageImage" runat="server" Height="7px"
           Width='<%# Eval("votsGraph") %>'
           ImageUrl="~/images/bar.JPG" />
```

So how do i cast this one?
(The type of `votsGraph` is float.)

Comment: Do note that this question is really *only* about VB.NET and not ASP.NET.

Comment: @pst In my answer I've also had to correct some ASP.NET Markup to get the OP's requirements, however.

Comment: @Curt Yes, and that's why it's up-voted and accepted ;-) Trying to show op that [modern] ASP.NET is just a layer on top of the underlying language/run-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CInt()`:

```
<asp:Image ID="PercentageImage" runat="server" Height="7px" Width='<%# string.format("{0}px", cint(Eval("votsGraph"))) %>' ImageUrl="~/images/bar.JPG" />
```

I've also added `String.Format()` to your code as you were missing `px`:

```
Width='<%# string.format("{0}px", cint(Eval("votsGraph"))) %>'
```